# Missing link to the package test_matlab

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to connect my ROS package to a MATLAB code. I am trying to test the package test_matlab_basic_ros. When I do a rosmake. I get the following error.

```
  /home/suraj/ROS_Packages/test_matlab_basic_ros/src/test_ros.cpp:44:33: fatal error: test_matlab/Vector3.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_ros.dir/src/test_ros.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/ROS_Packages/test_matlab_basic_ros/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_ros.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/ROS_Packages/test_matlab_basic_ros/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/ROS_Packages/test_matlab_basic_ros/build'
```

I am aware that I do not have the package test_matlab on my PC. But I was not able to checkout that from the link. The link does not exist.

https://usc-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/usc-ros-pkg/trunk/sandbox/matlab/test_matlab

Please let me know if there is alternative link. Or I have to make changes in the code.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41821/missing-link-to-the-package-test_matlab/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are using old and deprecated code that is not supported anymore. I'm not sure how the current state of matlab integration of ros is, but google was showing me [this link](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge). Maybe that's an alternative for you?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on 2012-08-20**:
Thanks for the information. I will try this method.